# Is it possible to play PCM samples in React Native?

Tags: javascript, react-native, buffer, pcm, speaker

I am trying to play real-time PCM samples which are coming from a TCP socket in React Native. I have found some libraries like  [react-native-sound-player](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-sound-player)  and  [react-native-simple-audio-player](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-simple-audio-player). However, none of them provide an interface to work with PCM samples of buffers. They can just play audios from a local file or a URL.

 Is there anyway to play raw PCM samples in React Native like the way [speaker](https://www.npmjs.com/package/speaker)  module in Node.Js?